# How reach the keybox in level 8?

Tags: vim-adventures

I am stuck on level 8:

[image: Level 8 of VIM-Adventures]

I would like to arrive at the key-box (I already have key.)
I guess I need `}` but I don't have this key yet, where is it if I need this?

My keyboard is as following [image: VIM adventures keyboard]

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like ) would be useful. You could then get to the last "You." and then do a # to go back to the "You,". Can you get ) in any way? I have not played game, so I have no idea.

Comment: Another letter that could help solve it would be '2', you could then do '2B' from "is" and get to the first "You,", and later by '*' to the last "You.".

Comment: Another idea I have is to type 'G$' but I'm not sure if game will allow it. In vim it is not a single move, it first navigates to the beginning of the last line and after that to the end of that line.

Comment: Dear @slawek thank you for your reply. Yes, I would like to get to the last "You.", and do a # to go back, however, I don't know how to get the last "You."

Comment: Dear @slawek thank you for your reply. Firstly, I don't have the key `)`. Secondly, I cannot use number `2`. Thirdly, it is not allowed to use `G` in this case, since "who" is in the black space. I can only use function keys as shown in the keyboard picture, which are collected in the previous level. Maybe I need to go back to find some missing function-key before doing this puzzle. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, I think it should be possible for you to mark your own answer as accepted, making the question answered. After that the question wouldn't pop up on unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I find the method. I have to use the whole picture instead of the original half picture.[image]

Comment: Great that you found solution. I guess thinking out of box was requried :) I would encourage you to post full solution to this puzzle, not only this hint. You could mark it as "spoiler" so the full solution would not be visible at first. In that way this question would be complete and would be even more helpful for others.

Comment: It is about You on the right half picture :)

Comment: I can press * and # on the right half of the picture..

Comment: How do get the whole screen? It always automatically scrolls for me and thus I am not able to jump from the You on the right to one on the left.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer only provides some hints. Here I would like to give a more detailed explanation.

1. Get "n" behind the blue door using "#"
2. Go to a "You" on the right and initiate a "#"
3. Now, move to the left text "rue". You will see that "Yue"s on the left are also highlighted. Then type "n" to repeat the search and you will reach the target "You".